# Parsing Issue - Angular and Nodejs

Tags: node.js, parsing, angular7

I have a form in angular. When I submit the form , it will hit the backend (written in nodejs - Sending an email functionality). In my local its working properly. But when I deployed in the cloud(here m using GCP- Deployed as  a standard environment), M getting an error like as follows.

> `Error occured in sending Email .  {headers: d, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "https://coffycloud.com/send", ok: false, …} error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anon... message: "Http failure during parsing for https://coffycloud.com/send"`

I have gone thru many posts in SO. I have changed the responseType as text but no use. Please let me know where m I doing wrong.

Service

```
export class ReachusService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  //Reach Us Service 
  private serializeObj(obj) {
  var result = [];
  for (var property in obj)
    result.push(encodeURIComponent(property) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[property]));

    return result.join('&');
  }
  baseUrl = "/send";
  sendMail(user: User) {
  console.log("User Details ", user);
  return this.http.post(this.baseUrl, this.serializeObj(user), { headers: { 'responseType': 'text', 
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*','Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }})
     .subscribe(
    (data: any) => {
      console.log("Mail has been sent to you ");
    },
    err => {
      console.log("Error occured in sending Email", err);
    }
    );
    }
    }
```

Comment: Did you check that hitting on backend?, or your getting error in angular side?

Comment: I have hit the backend . The status was 200. But when i console it gave me this error. And I checked my mail. Its not sent

Comment: @LakshmiYogeshwaran are you still into this issue. can you provide some more information on the server side code as well like how do you send a response to frontend on sendEmail functionality. also with respect to above comment did you console it on frontend or backend.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a shot in the dark here... Not really enough here to answer the question.

How are you routing between your front end and your backend, are you sure /send isn't just leading to the index.html? (that would explain the response starting with <, it's html you're getting back)

As for why you're not able to see the text... responseType is supposed to be passed directly in the options, not in the header.

```js
return this.http.post(
    this.baseUrl,
    this.serializeObj(user),
    { responseType: 'text',
      headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }})
```

https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient

Comment: Yes I'm sure about the routing. And thanks for your comment. I will change the responsetype and will check. But my question is y is it not working only after deploying in cloud. Previously It was working fine.

Comment: How does your routing differ between local development and cloud deployment if at all? Anyway try the response type and update with what it’s getting back, that’ll make it easier to determine what the issue is.